# Avoiding Segmentation Fault in .oct function?

Tags: c++, octave

This is mainly directed at users of Octave.

In the c++ API documentation for Octave, one of the examples is a function that adds two matrices like so:

```
*/addtwomatrices.cc
#include <octave/oct.h>
DEFUN_DLD (addtwomatrices, args, , "Add A to B")
{
  if (args.length () != 2)
    print_usage ();

  NDArray A = args(0).array_value ();
  NDArray B = args(1).array_value ();

 return octave_value (A + B);
}
```

Link: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Matrices-and-Arrays-in-Oct_002dFiles.html#Matrices-and-Arrays-in-Oct_002dFiles

which works fine and compiles without errors.
When using it in Octave though, if the function is called with the incorrect number of arguments, it seg faults and exits the program and dumps octave-core.

Is there a way to keep octave open even if this function is called with the incorrect number of arguments? 
For example,

```
addtwomatrices(5)
octave 1> "Incorrect Number of Arguments Supplied. Please provide 2."
octave 2>'
```

Instead of

```
Invalid call to addtwomatrices.  Correct usage is:

Adds 2 matrices
Additional help for built-in functions and operators is
available in the on-line version of the manual.  Use the command
`doc <topic>' to search the manual index.

Help and information about Octave is also available on the WWW
at http://www.octave.org and via the help@octave.org
mailing list.
panic: Segmentation fault -- stopping myself...
attempting to save variables to `octave-core'...
save to `octave-core' complete
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the online manual for the last release of Octave (4.2.1), but you are not using Octave 4.2.1.  You need to check the documentation for your Octave version:

- [Documentation for "Matrices and Arrays in Oct-Files" in Octave 4.0.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Matrices-and-Arrays-in-Oct_002dFiles.html)
- [Documentation for "Matrices and Arrays in Oct-Files" in Octave 4.2.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Matrices-and-Arrays-in-Oct_002dFiles.html)

If you were using an Octave 4.2.X release, then it would behave as you expected:

```
$ cat addtwomatrices.cc 
#include <octave/oct.h>
DEFUN_DLD (addtwomatrices, args, , "Add A to B")
{
  if (args.length () != 2)
    print_usage ();

  NDArray A = args(0).array_value ();
  NDArray B = args(1).array_value ();

 return octave_value (A + B);
}
$ mkoctfile-4.2.1 addtwomatrices.cc 
$ octave-cli-4.2.1 -q
octave-cli-4.2.1:1> addtwomatrices (5)
error: Invalid call to addtwomatrices.  Correct usage is:

Add A to B
octave-cli-4.2.1:1>
$ mkoctfile-4.0.0 addtwomatrices.cc 
$ octave-cli-4.0.0 -q
octave-cli-4.0.0:1> addtwomatrices (5)
error: Invalid call to addtwomatrices.  Correct usage is:

Add A to B
panic: Segmentation fault -- stopping myself...
Segmentation fault
```

The way errors are handling in Octave's libinterp changed in 4.2.  If you are using an older version, you need to handle the return of the function yourself.  You should instead do this:

```
#include <octave/oct.h>
DEFUN_DLD (addtwomatrices, args, , "Add A to B")
{
  if (args.length () != 2)
    {
      print_usage ();
      // In octave 4.2, print_usage also throws exceptions
      // and exist the function.  This is the same behaviour
      // in Octave m language.  In Octave 4.0, it only prints
      // the usage and then you still need to return otherwise
      // it continues execution of the function.
      return octave_value (); 
    }

  NDArray A = args(0).array_value ();
  NDArray B = args(1).array_value ();

 return octave_value (A + B);
}
```